# Firebase FCM w/ Topic average delivery time to the clients

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are developing a mobile online game that can be played by hundreds of people in each game room and intend to use push notifications(FCM) with topics to convey information about game progress to many users.

In each game room, hundreds of users would be subscribing to the same topic, and I want to know how long on average it takes for a push notification to be delivered to the client using the same topic.

If the delivery time of push notifications using topics is not fast enough, I would appreciate it if you could tell me which method is better to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fanout of topics in Firebase Cloud Messaging's backend systems is optimized for total system throughput and not for the latency of any individual topic.

Whether it is "fast enough" is subjective and only you can determine what is fast enough for your project, but the only way to have control over the performance of the mapping is to do it yourself.